# Python object has no referrers but still accessible via a weakref?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, cpython

Should it be possible for gc.get_referrers(obj) to return an empty list for an object, but the object still be accessible through a weak reference?

If so how would I start trying to identify the cause for this object not being garbage collected?

Edit: I'm not sure exactly how a code sample would help in this case - there's obviously a strong reference somewhere, but I'll be damned if I can find it. I was of the impression that all strong references to an object would be identified by get_referrers().

**Edit: Solved**. I found the variable with a strong reference - It was inside the game event loop but wasn't a class variable so get_referrers wasn't picking it up.

Comment: please give a simple code example. otherwise it's not clear what you mean. is the weak reference itself accessible or is the referenced object itself accessible through the weakref?

Comment: How did you find the variable with the reference? I'm trying to track down just such a leak but it's intermittent and gc.get_referrers is returning []. Is there a way to find where the "local" reference to the object is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html

A weak reference won't be keeping the object alive.

The get_referrers() function will only locate those containers which support garbage collection; extension types which do refer to other objects but do not support garbage collection will not be found.

What makes you think the object isn't getting collected? Also, have you tried gc.collect()?

Comment: I still get an object instance through my weakref, when I'd expect a None.

Comment: Are you certain there is not a strong reference elsewhere?  Also garbage collection is not automatic (even with ref counting, if there is a cycle of references those will wait until a different garbage collection algorithm is used)

Comment: Yes, but for how long?  Forever? ie, you leave the program running for a long, long time, and the object never collects?  Python's GC is generational, so it may take some time for the object to get collected.

Answer (score 1):

It might also be the case that a reference was leaked by a buggy C extension, IMHO you will not see the referer, yet still the refcount does not go down to 0. You might want to check the return value of `sys.getrefcount`.

Answer (score 1):

I am glad you have found your problem, unrelated to the initial question. Nonetheless, I have a different take on the answer for posterity, in case others have the problem.

It IS legal for the object to have no referrers and yet not be garbage collected.

From the Python 2.7 manual: "An implementation is allowed to postpone garbage collection or omit it altogether — it is a matter of implementation quality how garbage collection is implemented, as long as no objects are collected that are still reachable."

The NO-OP garbage collector is legal.

The discussions about generational and reference-counting garbage collectors are referring to a particular CPython implementation (as tagged in the question)

Answer (score 0):

As [Christopher says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127836/python-object-has-no-referrers-but-still-accessible-via-a-weakref/1127854#1127854), a weak reference does not count into object refcount, and therefore is not able to keep Python from deleting an object.

However, Python's garbage collector does not delete objects that are in a circular reference and have a `__del__` method defined.
You can check (and fix) such situation by using [gc.garbage](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.garbage).

Comment: gc.garbage is an empty list after calling gc.collect() - neither the object nor its superclasses define __del__. Would circular references be identifiable by the list returned by gc.get_referrers()?

Answer (score 0):

If you do have a strong reference to the object, use gc.get_referrers(obj) to find it.

This can help if you have a leak and don't know what's leaking:

http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph.py
http://mg.pov.lt/blog/hunting-python-memleaks
http://mg.pov.lt/blog/python-object-graphs.html

It's a thin wrapper around the inspect module; it can help a lot if you have hard-to-track unwanted references.  For just tracking down a reference, though, gc.get_referrers is probably all you need.